# Spark SQL - SQL scripts processing

Tags: sql, cassandra, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Spark and would like to know if there is any possibility to pass Spark an SQL script for processing.

My goal is to bring data from both mysql through jdbc and Cassandra into Spark and pass an SQL script file without having to modify it or minimal modifications applied to it. The reason why I'm saying minimal modifications is that I have a lot of SQL scripts (similar structure to stored procedures) which I don't want to convert them manually to RDD.

Main purpose is to process the data (execute these SQL scripts) through Spark, thus taking advantage of its capabilities and speed.

Answer (score 0):

This guy found a pretty general way to run sql scripts, just pass in the connection to your database:

https://github.com/syncany/syncany/blob/15dc5344696a800061e8b363f94986e821a0b362/syncany-lib/src/main/java/org/syncany/util/SqlRunner.java

One limitation is that each of the statements in your SQL script has to be delimited with a semi-colon. It basically just parses the script like a text document and executes each statement as it goes. You could probably modify it to take advantage of Spark's SQLContext, instead of using a Connection.

In terms of performance, it probably won't be as fast as a stored procedure because you're bottle-necking with the InputStream. But it is a work-around.